# codeigniter undefined index issue

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

This is fairly simple and I'm even doing something similar in a different part of the site and it works. I'm new to codeigniter so it could be just a simple mistake.

I'm getting this error:

> Message: Undefined index: username

```
function add($file){
    $user = $this->session->userdata('userid');
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE ID = '$user'");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    echo var_dump($result);
    echo '<br />';
    echo $result['username'];
    //........
```

When I echo a var_dump, I get the following:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#20 (1) { ["username"]=> string(5) "jesse" } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access username from result array you should use a `foreach` for that

But I guess in your case you are getting only one record from your query

So you can use `row_array()` instead of `result_array()`.

In this case (using `row_array()`), you can access `username` as `$result["username"]`.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you.I guess that's why it was working on another part of the site. I was using basically the same code, but had it running through a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can get username in any one below methods.

Method 1:

```
$result = $query->result_array();

echo $result[0]["username"];
```

Method 2.

```
$result = $query->row(); // returns first record.

echo $result->username;
```

Method 3.

```
$result = $query->row_array(); 

echo $result["user_name"];
```

Method 4.

```
$result = $query->first_row();

echo $result->username;
```